# How to display "divs" horizontally?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="Content">
    <div id="loginContent"></div>
    <div id="signupContent"></div>
</div>
```

I have a root div here. I want to display the child divs horizontally. How to do this?

Comment: Change their display, use flexbox, use css grids, there are lots of options.

Comment: They already display horizontally by default, so I imagine you mean vertically?

Comment: Copy paste your question title in Google.

Comment: The issue is, if I change the display(inline-block) or float(left), they both go to left with the second div lying under the first one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean this?

#### Flexbox:

```
#Content {
  display: flex;
}

#loginContent {
  flex: 1;
}

#signupContent {
  flex: 1;
}
```

#### Floats:

```
#loginContent,
#signupContent {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

#### Inline-block:

```
#Content {
  text-align: center;
}

#loginContent,
  #signupContent {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The issue is, if I change the display(inline-block) or float(left), they both go to left with the second div lying under the first one..

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4j88ywL/):

```
#loginContent, #signupContent {
display: inline-block;
```

}

or you can use float [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qx4z5ej0/):

```
#signupContent {
float: right;
```

}